# Windows 8 Open Desktop IE10

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, windows-8

When IE10 is the default browser on Windows 8, and Internet Options -> Programs -> Choose How You Open Links is set to `Always in Internet Explorer`, when you open a new process by URL, it opens in Metro version of IE10.

There are 2 ways around this that I can think of, but I haven't found a way for either yet.

1. Pass an argument to `iexplore.exe` that tells it to open on the desktop.
2. Programatically change the value of that Internet Option in the registry, open the URL, then set it back to whatever it was set to previously.

I have a feeling that #2 is the route I'd have to go down, however, looking in the registry at `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings` I can't see anything that would even remotely resemble that setting.

Has anybody tackled this problem before and can provide any insight?

***This is NOT an ethical problem - I simply need to know where the setting is, or if there's a way to force it into desktop via an argument. I really REALLY don't need to know that this isn't ideal; I'm fully aware of that fact already.***

Comment: If the user wants web pages to open in the new style of IE, then let them. Don't override user preferences.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks, but this wasn't an ethical question - It's a **requirement** that it opens in desktop mode. We pin an application to the side to do screen recording and provide the users with tasks to perform in the browser, if it's in Metro, they can't see it and thus doesn't provide a good UX.

Comment: #2 is also using a global setting to manage a local problem. What if another app tried to open a URL before you change the setting back? Or, worse, what if someone attempted to change their default browser, and then you changed it back?

Comment: @RogerLipscombe I don't want to change their default browser, I want to change an IE-Specific internet setting for less than a second. These concerns are entirely irrelevant in the scope of the question. Again, this isn't an ethical question.

Comment: @RudiVisser: It is an ethical question unless you state categorically in your original question that you either "own" these computers (corporate, e.g.) or that the user has consented to you making these changes.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe Let me edit my categorical statement in.

Comment: That's not a statement that you own the computers, that's a statement that you don't care that your program's being annoying.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe It's not being annoying - **it's performing it's purpose**. If I owned the computers I would use Group Policy to force it. I'm not affecting users' choice here (apart from maybe for 300ms whilst I launch it).

Comment: You *are* affecting the user's choice. The user chose to open Web pages in the new style of IE, and you are overriding the user's choice. Programs which ignore user settings are a source of complaints about Windows. "I told Windows to do X, but it doesn't do X. Windows sucks." (And if your program crashes during that 300ms window, your "temporary" change became permanent.)

Comment: @RaymondChen Yes I fully understand this, but the point of the application is desktop testing. If they're not in the desktop it can't be tested. Would you rather I denied these users the choice to use my application? *"Sorry, you're using Windows 8; Bye!"* That wouldn't go down well either. This is the lesser of two evils.

Comment: If you want complete control, you might want to consider just hosting an instance of IE via WinForms/WPF.

Comment: @WiredPrairie Unfortunately that's not appropriate; I need to launch their default browser.

Answer (score 2):

Now that we understand your scenario (automated testing), we can explain how to do this correctly, and it doesn't involve overriding any user settings, not even temporarily. It also works even if the user set their default browser to something other than Internet Explorer.

What you do is [open an explicit Desktop version of Internet Explorer and navigate it to your site](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/11/18/10238335.aspx). Here's an example in JavaScript. You can adapt this to C# with a little bit of importing, or you can go for the overachiever solution and just host IE inside your C# application.

```
var ie = new ActiveXObject("InternetExplorer.Application");
ie.Visible = true;
ie.Navigate("http://www.microsoft.com/");
WScript.Sleep(5000); // five seconds, say
ie.Quit();
```

Comment: This may work, but I'd now have to detect if IE's actually their default browser in the first place to be able to run alternative code.

Comment: @RudiVisser You already had to do this to detect which browser setting you need to modify (desktop IE vs new IE, desktop Firefox vs new Firefox, etc.)

Comment: Ah yes, but not just yet. Fx hasn't released it yet, and from my tests Chrome doesn't launch in full screen mode when invoked by URL as default.

Answer (score 0):

[How to force IE to open in desktop mode on Windows 8](http://regularitguy.com/2012/12/05/how-to-force-ie-to-open-in-desktop-mode-on-windows-8/)

If a user WANTS it in Metro and work all in the time in Metro, would be pretty annoying for him to switch back to desktop mode when using a URL. Hopefully, that webpage is what you want.

Comment: That's not what I want - Again, I know how to change the setting since it's in my post explicitly what was said in that article. I need a way to programmatically force them into desktop, not by asking them to change their preferences.

Comment: And it's why I said (implicitly, sorry) it might not be possible since it's a user property.